# How To Join and Print Two MongoDB Collections Using PHP

Tags: mongodb

These are two collections

```
lb_order_details
lb_orders
```

Can anyone suggest to me how to join -- like MySQL join -- and print these two MongoDB data collections using PHP?

Comment: -1 for not doing proper research.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as join in mongodb but you can create relation by   keeping id field common in every collection for specific user. You have to manage your database wisely to overcome join issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are no joins in MongoDB. You need to retrieve data with two distinct MongoDB queries and deal with data on PHP side.